# Android: insert new raw contact

Tags: android, contactscontract

I would like to insert a new raw contact. I'm sure this involve some sort of getContentProvider().insert using a ContactsContract uri of some sort. Can anyone show an example using a ContentValues to to insert a brand new contact?

(Update)
There is an excellent example in the SDK

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was having the same problem. I hope this helps you.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add new contact to device, please make sure you have at one list account, and you must indicate this account by `RawContact(ACcount Name, Account Type)`.